# How can I run PowerShell scripts from VirtualBox shared folders when using remote signed execution policy?

Tags: virtualbox, powershell, shared-folders

I'm using VirtualBox with a shared folder mapped to drive E:. I want to run a PowerShell script from drive E:. I set:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Remotesigned
```

I added `file://vboxserver` using the advanced dialog to the local intranet.

When I load `"E:\System_Data_SQLClient_test.ps1"` into PowerShell ISE I get:

> File E:\System_Data_SQLClient_test.ps1 cannot be loaded. The file
>   E:\System_Data_SQLClient_test.ps1 is not digitally signed. The
>   script will not execute on the system. Please see "get-help
>   about_signing" for more details.
>
> At line:0 char:0

When I use the UNC path to the shared folder it works:

```
\\VBOXSVR\WSV-BK-7en64-C\System_Data_SQLClient_test.ps1
```

What is missing here to be able to access the script via drive letter?

Comment: How do you execute the command using the unc path? I'm trying to do the same things with a simple string output script but it trows me the same error as if try to execute it with the drive letter. When i first read you problem I though it refers to te situation described here http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/01/04/run-powershell-scripts-stored-on-a-central-file-share.aspx but after check the file properties of any file in the share i see that they don't have the zone identifier so the problem is other thing. Maybe is the file type of the share, a weird VBoxSharedFolderFS

Comment: I'm always using ISE. I load either the script from a local disk, via unc from the shared folder or via drive letter from the latter shared folder.

Comment: I change the execution-policy to "unrestricted" and perhaps that it trows me a security warning message, in that message i have to select "run once" and the script run. But is weird, it recognized that is a external location even if the files don't have the Zone.Identifier. I think that definetilly has something to do with the way that VirtualBox create that share.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

bernd_k i found a nice solution to execute all the script that you have in the shared folder, create a directory symlink to the share, that is all!!

Suppose the actual location is c:\users\x. Run this in cmd as admin:

```
 mklink /d NameforMyScriptFolder \\vboxsvr\share\RealScriptFolder
```

then go to that folder, in powershell as normal user and run whatever you want:

```
  cd c:\users\x\NameforMy*
  executewhateverscript.ps1 #:D
```

pd: change the name of the question because it doesn't reflect what you really ask.

Comment: Please improve your answer by adding that you have to add 'file://vboxsvr' to Local Intranet Sites.

Comment: Hi bernd_k I don't know what you mean with "add to Local Intranet Sites", could you tell me more about it?...and in my configuration the only thing that i need was to set the execution policy as remotesigned and create the symlink

Comment: You seem to have reduced some security defaults. To give you a hint cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559969/how-to-programmatically-add-site-to-local-intranet-zone and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/972345/programmatically-add-trusted-sites-to-internet-explorer. Usually I do it with the GUI, sorry I find no link with pictures. You have to start IE| Tools| Internet options | security | local intranet | sites | Advanced. There you can add file://vboxsvr.

Comment: mmm I think that is completely unnecesary and unrelated to powershell script execution, remove it from the trusted list and try to run the scripts

Comment: For me it is definite necessary, when the script is not on a local drive. I rechecked it 2 times.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the working solution

```
Add file://vboxsvr to Local Intranet Sites

Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned

mklink /d hostfiles \\VBOXSVR\WSV-BK-7en64-C
```

Thanks to voodoomsr for giving this alternative way avoiding drive letters.

The main problem is to remember the correct syntax when adding the share to local Intranet.